# C# FileInfo Name foreach

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
FileInfo finfo = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "cleo", file.Key));

DialogResult modifiedcleofiles = MessageBox.Show("error", "error title", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning); 
if(modifiedcleofiles == DialogResult.OK)
{
    Message.Info(finfo.Name); //It prints filename ok
    if (!Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "gs", "CLEO"))) 
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "gS", "CLEO"));

    foreach (FileInfo filemove in finfo) //I don't know how to make foreach
    {
        filemove.MoveTo(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "gS", "CLEO", filemove.Name));
    }
}
```

So it's my problem. This code works fine without foreach, it works with:

```
finfo.MoveTo(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "gS", "CLEO", finfo.Name));
```

It's ok, but if there are more than 2 files, etc.. It shows two messageboxes.. I wan't to move all **finfo** files. **NOTE all finfo files, not all files which exists in folder !** Thanks in advance :( P.S do not give -karma or etc, I'm newbie..

P.S I'm tried this code:

```
foreach (FileInfo filemove in finfo.Directory.EnumerateFiles()) {
    filemove.MoveTo(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "gS", "CLEO", filemove.Name));
}
```

It move's all files from that folder, but I need only finfo..

Comment: I think you need `Directory.EnumerateFiles`

Comment: @EmpereurAiman, nope, I'm tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

```
.Where(i => i.Extension.Equals(".finfo", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```

to the enumerable. Or better, use the other overload of `EnumerateFiles`:

```
foreach (FileInfo filemove in finfo.Directory.EnumerateFiles("*.finfo")) {
```

Also, note that `MoveTo` only works on the same logical drive. If that's not enough for you, you will need to add your own copy+delete method for moving files accross drives.

Comment: Are you kidding? .finfo is not a file ending.. finfo is this: FileInfo finfo = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "cleo", file.Key));

Comment: @Evaldas888 You might want to clear up your question a bit more, then - there is only one `finfo`.

Comment: Hoh, thanks so much. I'm changed your ("*.finfo") to (finfo.Name) and It's works !